# Reading PDF, TJ operator strange encoding

Tags: php, pdf

I'm currently trying to extract text from a PDF document, but I encountered some strange cases with the Tj operator. Normally I dealt with cases like these:

```
   Tc (SOME_TEXT) TJ
```

Now I encounter a case like this:

```
   Tm  [
        ( )1.828
        (5)1.841
        (2)1.828
        (2)1.828
        (4)1.841
        (9)1.828
        (.)1.828
        (6)1.841
        (4)
       ]
   TJ
```

Which converts to string '52249.64'. Now I have encountered yet another strange case:

Only info I could find is this: A string passed to Tj is always to be interpreted according to the Encoding or CMap for the font. (In this case I expect it is a CIDFont with a CMap)

```
Td  (
        \t\004\007\020\007\016\016\026\020
    )
Tj
```

I still don't understand. Are these some kind of indexes that indicate an offset in some kind of character array or do I have to decode these values? Thanks!

Comment: Threre's nothing strange with that. You know that there's a document (http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) where all this is explained?

Comment: @PauloSoares The link is dead. Do you remember a google-friendly title of the document?

Comment: @Hermann *"The link is dead. "* - You can retrieve the current PDF spec as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950220/1729265).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Paulo already indicated in his comment, you should first consult the PDF specification, i.e. currently ISO 32000-1 a free copy of which is provided by Adobe [here](http://adobe.com/go/pdfreference).

On the topic of text extraction you'll find in particular section *9.10 Extraction of Text Content*, especially:

> **9.10.2 Mapping Character Codes to Unicode Values**
>
> A conforming reader can use these methods, in the priority given, to map a character code to a Unicode value. Tagged PDF documents, in particular, shall provide at least one of these methods (see 14.8.2.4.2, "Unicode Mapping in Tagged PDF"):
>
> - If the font dictionary contains a **ToUnicode** CMap (see 9.10.3, "ToUnicode CMaps"), use that CMap to convert the character code to Unicode.
> - If the font is a simple font that uses one of the predefined encodings **MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**, or that has an encoding whose **Differences** array includes only character names taken from the Adobe standard Latin character set and the set of named characters in the Symbol font (see Annex D):
>
>   a) Map the character code to a character name according to Table D.1 and the font’s **Differences** array.
>
>   b) Look up the character name in the *Adobe Glyph List* (see the Bibliography) to obtain the corresponding Unicode value.
> - If the font is a composite font that uses one of the predefined CMaps listed in Table 118 (except Identity–H and Identity–V) or whose descendant CIDFont uses the Adobe-GB1, Adobe-CNS1, Adobe-Japan1, or Adobe-Korea1 character collection:
>
>   a) Map the character code to a character identifier (CID) according to the font’s CMap.
>
>   b) Obtain the registry and ordering of the character collection used by the font’s CMap (for example, Adobe and Japan1) from its **CIDSystemInfo** dictionary.
>
>   c) Construct a second CMap name by concatenating the registry and ordering obtained in step (b) in the format *registry*–*ordering*–UCS2 (for example, Adobe–Japan1–UCS2).
>
>   d) Obtain the CMap with the name constructed in step (c) (available from the ASN Web site; see the Bibliography).
>
>   e) Map the CID obtained in step (a) according to the CMap obtained in step (d), producing a Unicode value.
>
> NOTE Type 0 fonts whose descendant CIDFonts use the Adobe-GB1, Adobe-CNS1, Adobe-Japan1, or Adobe-Korea1 character collection (as specified in the **CIDSystemInfo** dictionary) shall have a supplement number corresponding to the version of PDF supported by the conforming reader. See Table 3 for a list of the character collections corresponding to a given PDF version. (Other supplements of these character collections can be used, but if the supplement is higher-numbered than the one corresponding to the supported PDF version, only the CIDs in the latter supplement are considered to be standard CIDs.)
>
> If these methods fail to produce a Unicode value, there is no way to determine what the character code represents in which case a conforming reader may choose a character code of their choosing.

<sup>*If some of the terms here are unknown to you, read about them in [ISO 32000-1](http://adobe.com/go/pdfreference) or the other specifications referenced there.*</sup>

**For an acceptable text extraction result, therefore, make your text extractor support the method presented in that section.**

Comment: Yes, i get that 503, too. On the other hand the Adobe.com/go URLs are meant to be more stable. Oh well, as ISO 32000-2 is now available for free, maybe they don't care.