# PDF Text Syntax: BT ET Block content

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, pypdf

Using `PyPDF2`, could able to parser the content of the PDF but for some PDFs i am getting following data:

```
Decoded Data:
...

BT
310.00 621.52 TD
/F1 12 Tf
[<0030004B004E004B005000460003003000430046004A0057004D00430054000300270047005100540047>] TJ
ET

...
```

How to decode the string before `Tj` i.e. `[<0030004B004E004B005000460003003000430046004A0057004D00430054000300270047005100540047>]`

My decoding code is something like following:

```
### get the content
pdf = PdfFileReader(self.in_file)

for page_number in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
    page = pdf.getPage(page_number)
    contents = page.getContents()

    ### adjust the contents...
    data = contents.get_data()
    encoding = chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
    decoded_data = data.decode(encoding)
    print(f'Decoded Data: {decoded_data}')
```

Comment: In the line before the **TJ** text showing instruction there is a **Tf** text font setting instruction. Simply look up the font **F1** set there in the font resources of your content stream. If it has a **ToUnicode** stream, use that. Otherwise try to use the **Encoding** entry. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33416913/1729265).

Comment: @mkl thanks for guiding me. I could find both `ToUnicode` and `Encoding`. I have limited idea to getting text in PDF with toUnicode, but let me give it a try. Kindly let me know if you can guide some code with? Thank a lot!

Comment: I don't have any Python code. I would assume, though, that there are numerous Python PDF libraries that support text extraction out-of-the-box, applying **ToUnicode** or **Encoding** under-the-hood.