# Why is my XREF table corrupt after removing or adding annotations?

Tags: pdf, itext7

I am evaluating iText 7 as alternative for our current PDF processing packages. I am creating a PoC where the input is a PDF document with containers (i.e. annotations). Logic should remove existing QR codes and then add new ones in the containers.

While the logic seems to work and the codes are removed and/or added, there are still issues with the modified file. It states there are errors with the XREF table. The error is introduced also if I only remove or add a code, so I thought the cause might be in the common code.

There seems to be no issue when you open the modified file in the browser. When opening with a advanced PDF editor a warning is shown. Resaving the file with the editor seems to fix the file, but that is not a solution.

I wonder where I went wrong and what to do to fix this or investigate it further. With the code below it is easy to reproduce. Any thoughts on this?

I'm testing with iText 7.1.11 in a .NET Core console application written with C#.

Main code for the process:

```
using (var pdfFileStream = new MemoryStream(pdfFileBytes))
{
  using (var outputFileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
  {
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFileStream);
    var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(outputFileStream);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

    var pageCount = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
    PdfPage page = null;
    IList<PdfAnnotation> annotations = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
      page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i + 1);
      annotations = page.GetAnnotations();

      if (annotations.Count == 0)
      {
        continue;
      }

      // Get QR code containers
      var containers = FilterAnnotations(annotations, containerName);

      if (containers.Count == 0)
      {
        continue;
      }

      // Get QR codes instances
      var instances = FilterAnnotations(annotations, instanceName);

      if (instances.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (var instance in instances)
         {
            RemoveQRCode(instance, page);
         }
      }

      foreach (var container in containers)
      {
         AddQRCode(container, page, pdfDocument, url);
      }

    }

    pdfDocument.Close();

    return outputFileStream.ToArray();
  }
}
```

I filter out the annotations I'd like to remove (i.e. the codes) by subject. The same goes for finding the containers where to put the code annotations:

```
private List<PdfAnnotation> FilterAnnotations(IList<PdfAnnotation> annotations, string subject)
{
  return annotations.Where(a =>
    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(GetSubject(a)) &&
    GetSubject(a).ToLowerInvariant().Equals(subject, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
}
```

Then I loop through the filtered annotations to remove them:

```
private void RemoveQRCode(PdfAnnotation annotation, PdfPage page)
{
  page.RemoveAnnotation(annotation);
}
```

The following code describes adding the codes:

```
private void AddQRCode(PdfAnnotation container, PdfPage page, PdfDocument document, string url)
{
  BarcodeQRCode qrCode = new BarcodeQRCode(url);
  PdfFormXObject qrCodeForm = qrCode.CreateFormXObject(ColorConstants.BLACK, document);

  var rectangle = GetRectangle(container);

  var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
  canvas
    .SaveState()
    .AddXObject(qrCodeForm, rectangle)
    .RestoreState();

  canvas.Release();

  PdfStampAnnotation stampAnnotation = new PdfStampAnnotation(rectangle);
  stampAnnotation.SetSubject(new PdfString(instanceName));
  stampAnnotation.SetAppearance(PdfName.N, new PdfAnnotationAppearance(qrCodeForm.GetPdfObject()));
  stampAnnotation.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);

  page.AddAnnotation(stampAnnotation);
}
```

I left out code for brevity.

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**

As per request of [@mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) [two files](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=02043899083506403411) of which test2_mod is the result. I also added more code. Thank you for your fast response.

Comment: *"With the code below it is easy to reproduce."* - as it contains `(...)`, it isn't. If the code required to actually reproduce the issue is too large, please share at least an input and a broken output file for analysis. That would probably allow to get an idea where the issue is located.

Comment: [@mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) Thank you for your fast response. I have updated my post with more code and a test file before and after processing. The latter is faulty.

Comment: *"there are still issues with the modified file. It states there are errors with the XREF table."* - Which programs exactly claim that there are errors?

Comment: I have tested with [PDF-XChange Editor Plus](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor). It might be a [minor issue](https://forum.manager.io/t/errors-detected-in-the-xref-table/22049), but it could become a serious one and moreover I'd like to produce valid outcomes conform [PDF specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111831/pdf-specifications-for-coders-adobe-or-iso).

Comment: Ok, indeed, iText 7 apparently still has that error.

Comment: Anyone on the iText7 dev team who can confirm this bug and/or help me pinpoint/fix the issue? I found that after running the AddQRCode method the PdfDocument.xref property has changed: [a lot more entries with NULL values](https://i.imgur.com/4sZm0Yx.png).

Comment: @JPuzzled, we do acknowledge the bug, and have created a ticket for it. The answer from mkl below would be a good workaround while we do not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem claimed by PDF-XChange Editor Plus here is indeed exactly the one explained in the [PDF-XChange forum entry](https://forum.tracker-software.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=32587#) referenced from the [forum entry](https://forum.manager.io/t/errors-detected-in-the-xref-table/22049) you linked in a comment

> Problem is very simple - XRef stream has incorrect **/Index** entry.
>
> ```
> /Index[0 185]/Size 186
> ```
>
> File has only one XRef section, which describe all objects in file, so this entry is optional. **/Size** entry is correct, since document has objects with maximum number 185, but **/Index** entry say that it has only 185 records instead of 186 required, and XRef stream itself does not contain record about last object (185, XRef stream itself). Normally this does not prevent PDF files to be opened by most readers, but does not conform PDF specification.

*([Response by Lzcat - Tracker Supp](https://forum.tracker-software.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=32587#p133543))*

When using cross reference streams, iText 7 also does not add an entry for the cross reference stream itself to the cross references, in case of your example document:

```
80 0 obj 
  [...] /Index[0 80] [...] /Size 81
```

The array value of **Index** here means that this cross reference stream contains 80 entries starting at 0, i.e. entries for object 0..79. But the cross reference stream here is in object 80, so it contains no entry for itself.

But indeed, the PDF specification requires

> Like any stream, a cross-reference stream shall be an indirect object. Therefore, an entry for it shall exist in either a cross-reference stream (usually itself) or in a cross-reference table (in hybrid-reference files; see 7.5.8.4, "Compatibility with Applications That Do Not Support Compressed Reference Streams").

*(ISO 32000-1, section 7.5.8.3 "Cross-Reference Stream Data")*

By the way, the example PDF from that support forum thread has creator and producer entries claiming that it has been created by "Apitron PDF Kit". Apparently iText is not the only library with this quirk.

#### A quick fix

I tried a quick fix for the issue; as I'm more into Java, I did it for the Java version of iText:

```java
protected void writeXrefTableAndTrailer(PdfDocument document, PdfObject fileId, PdfObject crypto) throws IOException {
    [...]
    if (writer.isFullCompression()) {
        [...]
        xrefStream.put(PdfName.Size, new PdfNumber(this.size()));

        // vvv--- add these two lines
        xrefStream.getIndirectReference().setOffset(startxref);
        sections = createSections(document, false);

        int offsetSize = getOffsetSize(Math.max(startxref, size()));
```

*(kernel module class `PdfXrefTable`)*

It should look very similar in the C# version of iText 7, merely initials of method names are capitalized.

Beware, though, this is merely smoke tested. For production use, much more testing is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the issue. I'm aware of the forum posts. We (think to) know _what_ the problem is. The question remains _how_ to fix it. I only did some tests with annotations. I'm not sure whether other actions result in a malformed XREF table. If so solving the issue might get a higher priority. And please do let me know if I can help, although I'm no PDF/iText7 expert.

Comment: Essentially it is a bug in iText 7, and you can only fix it by changing the iText code itself. Also it is unrelated to whether you change annotations or content or metadata or something else entirely; as long as the PDF is stored using cross reference streams (and not cross reference tables), the same (generally harmless) error happens, the cross reference stream object does not reference itself.