# working with imageinformation and paths in pdfs

Tags: python, pdf

everything what has to do with PDF is a miracle to me.
There are some problems I have to solve but I don't find information about it.

1. Searching for Spotcolors. Does it exist? Whats the name of it etc, is it set to "overprint"?
2. Search for paths ( in Illustrator its a Shape with a contur with a spotcolor ) and split the closed paths to single pdf pages.
3. Include / Exclude imageinformation within the closed path
4. Get the size of the seperated paths.

Can somebody help to find a start on this? Where can I find information about this kind of "pdf-manipulation"?

best regards,

Comment: I'm assuming you're dealing with something in printing; many of these things are very familiar to me. If you need to write this from scratch without using higher-level tools, you need to at least have a look at the PDF Specification (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111831/pdf-specifications-for-coders-adobe-or-iso/14115129#14115129). Concepts such as spot colors are described in there, even though the terminology will be different (separation colors). You'll also need a library that will give you basic PDF support, to the level of page elements...

Comment: Hello, sorry for answering so late. I did take a look at the linked documents and will try to reproduce some things. editing, deleting some lines in notepad, monitor changes to find a way to achieve what I'm looking for.