# How are pdfs build?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Where do I find information about how a pdf is made up?
For example: A pdf I created named `Dokname` containing the string `TEST` opend in a text-editor looks like this:
(I replaced the parts the text-editor couldn't decode with [...])

```
%PDF-1.4
%Óëéá
1 0 obj
<</Title (Dokname)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m102 Google Docs Renderer)>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 160>> stream
[...]
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Resources <</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/ExtGState <</G3 3 0 R>>
/Font <</F4 4 0 R>>>>
/MediaBox [0 0 596 842]
/Contents 5 0 R
/StructParents 0
/Parent 6 0 R>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [2 0 R]>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog
/Pages 6 0 R>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Length1 14972
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 7164>> stream
[...]
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /AAAAAA+ArialMT
/Flags 4
/Ascent 905.27344
/Descent -211.91406
/StemV 45.898438
/CapHeight 715.82031
/ItalicAngle 0
/FontBBox [-664.55078 -324.70703 2000 1005.85938]
/FontFile2 8 0 R>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/FontDescriptor 9 0 R
/BaseFont /AAAAAA+ArialMT
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/CIDSystemInfo <</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (Identity)
/Supplement 0>>
/W [0 [750] 40 54 666.99219 55 [610.83984]]
/DW 0>>
endobj
11 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 243>> stream
[...]
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /AAAAAA+ArialMT
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [10 0 R]
/ToUnicode 11 0 R>>
endobj
xref
0 12
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000365 00000 n 
0000000098 00000 n 
0000008721 00000 n 
0000000135 00000 n 
0000000573 00000 n 
0000000628 00000 n 
0000000675 00000 n 
0000007925 00000 n 
0000008159 00000 n 
0000008407 00000 n 
trailer
<</Size 12
/Root 7 0 R
/Info 1 0 R>>
startxref
8860
%%EOF
```

What do these `obj`-elements represent? Where is my `TEST`? Why did it get scrambled?

What I am searching for can probably all be found in adobe's [documentations](https://www.pdfa.org/resource/pdf-specification-index/), but those have hundreds of pages which is very overwhelming. I get that this is a very complex topic and I am not trying to understand it completely. Just looking for an introduction or an overview. Unfontunately I didn't find anything like that on youtube or elsewhere..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDF specifications for coders: Adobe or ISO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111831/pdf-specifications-for-coders-adobe-or-iso)

Answer (score 1):

Too complex for comments and yes you will only find snippets here and there including this and bits in my and others answers.

For a quick overview of the code sample you provided

A pdf is a collection of **obj**ects which are placed in no sequential order. So you start at the end before the last %%EOF (potentially one of many !) with `startxref 8860` where 8860 is the decimal address of the Cross(XRef)erence table i.e. the files index.

There are many abbreviations (too many to list) and like a stack language most things may appear (literally) backwards so the xref points to each objects position in the file.

The prime target in this case is `7 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 6 0 R>> endobj` since the catalog tells us about where the number of following pages will be found thus in object 6 `/Pages /Count 1 /Kids [2 0 R]` so its one page further defined in 2 0 obj

We now see there is an image and font(s) placed within /MediaBox [0 0 596 842] which is roughly (a tad wider) than a standard A4 page since 595/72" is closer to 210 mm.

Too much to describe about that one item alone, so skipping to ***Where is your text?*** and we see `/Contents 5 0 R` so that compressed stream of data that you need to decode is most likely your text but the length (/Length 160) is the binary flate encoded stream with placements not just your raw plain text.

The quantity of date sub setting the font seems odd and excessive for just 4 letters (if it was similar Helvetica it would not need including nor breaking the font as CID ArialMT) and without the full file its hard to say why the words /Image* is there, but it is Google Docs Renderer!

My suspicion is we may see characteristics of OCR in that stream.