# How to generate a proper PDF file?

Tags: pdf-generation

I made a program that generates PDF files. Those files are fairly simple – text (CID Type 2), vector graphics, images, stream filters too. When I open a file generated by my program in Adobe Reader, it looks alright. But when I close it, the Reader asks me whether I want to save changes made to the file, even though I didn't make any. I use Adobe Reader XI. As I've read, this usually happens when the file is corrupted.

---

Tried some experiments.

<strike>I created the "Simple Text String Example" as described in the [documentation](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#G21.1017053) (using Notepad and a hex editor). This worked fine. But then I added a comment and upon closing the save dialog box showed up. Obviously, there is no way the file with comment would be corrupted and the file without comment would not.</strike> I actually forgot to change the offsets in xref table when I added the comment...

Then I created a PDF using MS Word (MS 365) and trimmed off everything unnecessary. Metadata, information dictionary, logical structure, marked content, XRef stream, ... until the file looked almost like the files generated by my program. I was trying to get to the point where the Reader would give me the save prompt. But even after all these modifications, there was no prompt.

I also tried opening these "corrupted" files in other PDF readers (Foxit, Google Chrome, Slim PDF Reader) and they seemingly have no problems with the files.

---

So, I have two questions:

- Is there anything wrong with the files that Adobe Reader asks me to save? And if so,
- What can I do to fix them? Are there any "minimal requirements that a PDF should meet" which I might have overlooked in the PDF specification?

**Edit**: Here's the file I made. I think it is better to share the whole file instead of code snippet, because the file is fairly big and contains binary data

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cqc73o6s9arney1s7308b/test.pdf?rlkey=uuec9c8am6li5lm0jurw3oe70&dl=0

Comment: It would be easiest if you shared the pdf in question. There are so many things one can get wrong...

Comment: *"Here's the file I made."* - Wow, that's big for an early attempt at creating PDFs... First error: You have `/Size 10` in the trailer but you do have objects 1 through 10, so it should  be `/Size 11`.

Comment: Second error: your xref table entries are too short, 19 bytes instead of 20.

Comment: With those two errors corrected, Acrobat here does not ask to save the file after closing anymore.

Comment: @mkl "_I made_" meaning "_my program made_" ;)

Comment: @KJ About the line feeds, a note in section 7.5.1: "_...lines that are not part of stream object data are limited to no more than 255 characters..._". To simplify things for myself I just decided to put them everywhere as a whitespace character. But I don't know, is it bad practice?

Comment: Concerning your reference to the note in ISO 32000-1, section 7.5.1: First of all, that's only a _note_ and doesn't have any ISO/RFC requirement indicator (no SHALL, no MUST), so one shouldn't consider this mandatory in spite of its definitive formulation. Furthermore, that note has been dropped in ISO 32000-2, the most current PDF spec. Thus, **don't expect PDFs you retrieve from the wild to restrict themselves to "lines" of no more than 255 characters.** Limiting to shorter lines may still be considered good style. But using line breaks everywhere is a bit too much for good style.

Comment: For an up-to-date copy of the current PDF spec, please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950220/1729265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example file, two errors are apparent:

- You have 11 entries in your xref table, the start of the free objects chain in at object number 0 and the existing objects 1 through 10. Thus, you have to declare the **Size** in the trailer as *11* but you have a *10* there.
- Your xref table entries are only 19 bytes long each but they must be 20 bytes long. Simply add a space (0x20) after each 'f' and 'n'.

With those issues fixed, Acrobat here does not ask to write the PDF anymore when closing. This does *not* necessarily mean that all bugs are fixed, merely those that Acrobat is very sensitive about.

Comment: Actually, only fixing the xref table entry lengths was enough to make Adobe Reader happy. Still, you're right, **Size** is supposed to be 11, not 10.

Comment: Indeed, Acrobat is very sensitive to issues in the cross references. But using a wrong **Size**, in particular a too small one, is asking for trouble when your file is post-processed by other PDF processors. So be sure to fix both issues.

Answer (score 1):

The examples in the "standard" are hypothetical and often will fail to work so I have corrected that page 708 example which is accepted by all readers except Acrobat, by alter the trailer to

```
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000075 00000 n 
0000000121 00000 n 
0000000181 00000 n 
0000000303 00000 n 
0000000382 00000 n 

trailer
<< /Size 7
/Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
407
%%EOF
```

I am confident those vales are correct for my edits as I use 2 other readers that would indicate flaws/errors in the trailer.
[image]

So  let us use their "Hello World" example as easier to prove the differences.
This works in all 3 reader tests both opening and closing without error.
[image]

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [ 4 0 R ]
/Count 1
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Contents 5 0 R
/Resources << /ProcSet 6 0 R
/Font << /F11 7 0 R >>
>>
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<< /Length 43 >>
stream
BT
/F1 24 Tf
100 100 Td
(Hello World) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
[/PDF /Text]
endobj

7 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Encoding /MacromanEncoding
>>
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000075 00000 n 
0000000121 00000 n 
0000000181 00000 n 
0000000326 00000 n 
0000000420 00000 n 
0000000449 00000 n 

trailer
<< /Size 8
/Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref
558
%%EOF
```

### So Points to note Line by Line.

- ALL lines are Linux terminated, so no "Carriage Returns" just linefeeds (0A) there are NO hex `0D` in this case (they would increase the values need by an extra byte per line).
- ALL lines are NOT indented (unlike the publication!) however their text string stream allows for padding!
- 2 0 Obj is in trailer at 75 **not 74** so from that point onwards the XREF is compromised by many other wrong values and that is why Acrobat wants to rewrite the whole file!
- Finally it is not clear from the illustration that all those xref lines ending `n` include a space character after the `n` (and `f`) because we are working *without* 2 byte Line terminations.

### Answers

Acrobat reader will significantly do a total rewrite of the file not just a simple correction of xref flaws, that most readers (itself included, may normally ignore)

Several better readers should be able to make smaller edits to bring the xref into correct linage. MuPDF-GL is the least likely to make sweeping changes, but can be used for tasks like redaction, form filling etc.

It will change the styling of object entries. Here is its remake with NO alterations made, simply save (note a small reduction in overall size).

```
%PDF-1.4
%µ¶

1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Outlines 2 0 R/Pages 3 0 R>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<</Type null/Count 0>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Kids[4 0 R]/Count 1>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 3 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Contents 5 0 R/Resources<</ProcSet 6 0 R/Font<</F11 7 0 R>>>>>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<</Length 43>>
stream
BT
/F1 24 Tf
100 100 Td
(Hello World) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

6 0 obj
[/PDF/Text]
endobj

7 0 obj
<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/Name/F1/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/MacromanEncoding>>
endobj

xref
0 8
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000077 00000 n 
0000000116 00000 n 
0000000168 00000 n 
0000000296 00000 n 
0000000388 00000 n 
0000000416 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 8/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
514
%%EOF
```

To create a fixed file you can run
`mutool clean in.pdf out.pdf` and it will fix any faults in the xref trailer (plus alter whitespace characters to produce a correct more compact file).

In.pdf  1,175,572 bytes
Out.pdf 1,175,486 bytes

With correct number of indexed entries and line padding for Linux/Mac EOLS.