# Creating a PDF in C Without Third-Party Libraries

Tags: c, pdf

I'm trying to create a basic PDF file using C without relying on any third-party libraries. I've put together some code to generate a minimal PDF with the text "Hello World," but it seems to be corrupted. I'd like to understand how this works better, and I'm not looking for a production-grade solution at this point. My goal is to learn the basics of PDF file structure and content.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE* pdfFile = fopen("hello_world.pdf", "wb");

    if (pdfFile == NULL) {

        perror("Error opening the file");

        return 1;

    }

    // PDF header

    fprintf(pdfFile, "%c%c%c%c", 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46);

    // PDF content

    fprintf(pdfFile, "1 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "2 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "3 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 4 0 R >> /ProcSet 5 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 6 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "4 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "5 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "[ /PDF /Text ]\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "6 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Length 44 >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "stream\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "BT\n/F1 24 Tf\n100 100 Td\n(Hello World) Tj\nET\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endstream\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    // Cross-reference table

    fprintf(pdfFile, "xref\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0 7\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000000 65535 f\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000009 00000 n\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000056 00000 n\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000116 00000 n\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000174 00000 n\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000270 00000 n\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000340 00000 n\n");

    // Trailer

    fprintf(pdfFile, "trailer\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "startxref\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "450\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "%%EOF\n");

    fclose(pdfFile);

    return 0;

}
```

When I attempt to open the resulting "hello_world.pdf" file, it appears to be corrupted. Could someone with experience in PDF file structure provide insights on what I might be missing or what's causing the corruption?

Again, I want to clarify that my primary goal is to understand the inner workings of PDF files rather than create a production-ready solution. Any explanations or pointers to resources for learning more about the PDF file format would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know the PDF format, but maybe generate the same file using a third-party library, then compare the output with what you have.

Comment: You might want to read [the PDF specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/75839.html).

Comment: Unrelated: why did you put a blank line between each end every line of your code?

Comment: I would expect in the first lines in comment information about: a) what the code shall do b) used references and documentation c) how the code shall do the work. This can help you to verify if you'r right and others to find if your code is right. -- and probably why not.

Comment: @pmg This doc is behind a paywall. I would try to use this: https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: Considering the specification, you can get the current one (ISO 32000-2:2020) for free from the PDF Association (sponsored by Adobe, Apryse, and Foxit), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950220/1729265). This is preferable to the old ISO 32000-1:2008 you can download from Adobe.

Comment: @Void *"it appears to be corrupted"* - how does that show? Can you not load the PDF in some PDF viewers? Or do they show something scrambled? Or do they warn about something?

Comment: One first hint, your header is missing the version number and an end-of-line before the next line.

Comment: Guys I am not expert in these that's why there are mistakes, if anyone can provide me working code that would be great !!

Comment: Nonetheless please clarify what you mean by *"it appears to be corrupted"* - we should know which issue bothers you the most.

Comment: Pdf viewer show "corrupted"

Answer (score 0):

If your header or trailer are incorrect you can expect many PDF readers like Acrobat may say something along the lines of:

> Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'rawb.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

If the header is good but trailer or content is poor, you may just see blank page(s).

Some viewers may allow fails in both and attempt to fix the shambles.

Basically your programming should work in a forgiving viewer without any more change than, tidy the first line so this is what it will look like,

[image]

When program output is like this WARTS and ALL. Note: I simply modified the first 2 lines so there are many other unconventional features, but it proves the first line is as important as the last.

DO NOT add `% PDF header comment` which I did the first line should be `%PDF-#.#` to signify to a reader what Acrobat versions contents to expect.

```
% PDF header
%PDF-1.0
% PDF content
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 >>
endobj

3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 4 0 R >> /ProcSet 5 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 6 0 R >>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman >>
endobj

5 0 obj
[ /PDF /Text ]
endobj

6 0 obj
<< /Length 44 >>
stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (Hello World) Tj ET
endstream
endobj
% Cross-reference table

xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000116 00000 n
0000000174 00000 n
0000000270 00000 n
0000000340 00000 n
% Trailer
trailer
<< /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
450
%%EOF

% fclose(pdfFile);
```

The most difficult part can be writing a good `xref` table as many viewers will choke if it's wrong but may work without it!

For working in MS CMD or MS Jscript it is easy to stack a set of running totals (like an array) then simply apply those line by line at the end.

Generally written like this Acrobat and most readers will NOT say there is any error.

```
%PDF-1.0
1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >> endobj
2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 >> endobj
3 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 4 0 R >> /ProcSet 5 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 6 0 R >> endobj
4 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman >> endobj
5 0 obj [ /PDF /Text ] endobj
6 0 obj << /Length 43 >> stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 100 100 Td (Hello World) Tj ET
endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000058 00000 n
0000000115 00000 n
0000000256 00000 n
0000000328 00000 n
0000000358 00000 n

trailer << /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
452
%%EOF
```

Most likely cause for rejection is: you can see my later xrefs are far off from your values.

BUT you must ensure the lines feeds in xref are one char away from the f & n 's. which does not show here because I pasted with windows CRLF (0D0A).

So the most obvious residual point to check is that PROC set definition may be surplus or better repositioned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get Adobe Acrobat Reader to read the PDF file with some changes to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char pdfhdr[]="%PDF-1.2";
    char pdfeof[]="%%EOF";

    FILE* pdfFile = fopen("hello_world.pdf", "wb");

    if (pdfFile == NULL) {

        perror("Error opening the file");

        return 1;

    }

    // PDF header

    for ( int i=0; i< 8; i++)
        fprintf(pdfFile, "%c",pdfhdr[i]);

    fprintf(pdfFile, "%c", '\n');

    // PDF content

    fprintf(pdfFile, "1 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "2 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 >>\n");
    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "3 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 4 0 R >> /ProcSet 5 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Contents 6 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "4 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Times-Roman >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "5 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "[ /PDF /Text ]\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "6 0 obj\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Length 44 >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "stream\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "BT\n/F1 24 Tf\n100 100 Td\n(Hello World) Tj\nET\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endstream\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "endobj\n");
 // Cross-reference table

    fprintf(pdfFile, "xref\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0 7\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000000 65535 f \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000009 00000 n \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000058 00000 n \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000115 00000 n \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000256 00000 n \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000328 00000 n \n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "0000000358 00000 n \n");

    // Trailer

    fprintf(pdfFile, "trailer\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "<< /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "startxref\n");

    fprintf(pdfFile, "451\n");

    for ( int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        fprintf(pdfFile, "%c",pdfeof[i]);

    fprintf(pdfFile,"%c",'\n');

    fclose(pdfFile);

    return 0;

}
```

You can avoid the hard-coding in some of the `fprintf` statements if you keep track of the file pointer offsets in the writes to your generated PDF file.

Your header and trailer should match the PDF specifications. Also the offsets for each PDF object in the XREF table entry should be correct. Apart from this each XREF PDF object entry should be exactly 20 characters long, including the end-of-line marker. If the end-of-line is a single character (either a carriage return or linefeed), it is preceded by a single space. If the end-of-line sequence is two characters (a carriage return followed by a linefeed), it is not preceded by a space. I ran the code on linux (gcc) , so had only a single character for the end of line marker, and the generated PDF file was opened on Acrobat Reader on Windows.

The generated XREF table looks like below:

```
xref
0 7
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000058 00000 n 
0000000115 00000 n 
0000000256 00000 n 
0000000328 00000 n 
0000000358 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Size 7 /Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
451
%%EOF
```

I suggest you open the generated PDF file with a suitable file hex viewer/editor and check that the XREF entries are correctly generated, as you cannot make the actual bytes in the PDF file with an usual text editor like Notepad. Even with an incorrect header and/or EOF , Adobe Acrobat Reader can manage to open such PDF files but if some XREF entries are incorrect, you may get an error message like : "There was an error opening this document. There was a problem reading this document (109)"

You can check the PDF you generate from code with any of the freely available PDF utilities. I used the Perl CAM::PDF package:

```
C:\>perl "c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\pdfinfo.pl" .\hello_world.pdf
File:         .\hello_world.pdf
File Size:    654 bytes
Pages:        1
Page Size:    variable
Optimized:    no
PDF version:  1.2
Security
  Passwd:     none
  Print:      yes
  Modify:     yes
  Copy:       yes
  Add:        yes
C:\>perl "c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\getpdfpage.pl" .\hello_world.pdf 1
    BT
    /F1 24 Tf
    100 100 Td
    (Hello World) Tj
    ET


C:\>perl "c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\getpdftext.pl" .\hello_world.pdf
Hello World

C:\>perl "c:\strawberry\perl\site\bin\listfonts.pl" .\hello_world.pdf
Page 1:
  Name: F1
    Type: Type1
    BaseFont: Times-Roman
    Widths: no
    Embedded: no
```