# On Very first of PDF spec. language's stream object is numbers sequence

Tags: pdf, iso-32000

What is the sequence of numbers on the first of a stream object in e.g.

```
218 0 obj
<< /Type /ObjStm /Length 8647 /N 100 /First 889 >>
stream
219 0 220 116 221 237 222 353 223 470 224 587 225 704 226 820 227 936 228 1053 229 1169 230 1286
231 1403 232 1520 233 1637 234 1754 235 1871 236 1984 237 2100 238 2217 239 2334 240 2451 241 256
8 242 2685 243 2802 244 2919 245 3036 246 3157 247 3274 248 3391 249 3508 250 3624 251 3741 252 3
857 253 3974 254 4091 255 4208 256 4325 257 4442 258 4559 259 4676 260 4775 261 4813 262 4930 263
 5046 264 5166 265 5287 266 5404 267 5525 268 5646 269 5763 270 5880 271 5997 272 6114 273 6230 2
74 6329 275 6592 276 6630 277 6663 278 6678 279 6712 280 6728 281 6765 282 6784 283 6816 284 6830
 285 6871 286 6894 287 6927 288 6942 289 6978 290 6996 291 7024 292 7034 293 7071 294 7090 295 71
24 296 7140 297 7174 298 7190 299 7225 300 7242 301 7281 302 7311 303 7340 304 7351 305 7386 306
7403 307 7438 308 7455 309 7491 310 7509 311 7539 312 7551 313 7577 314 7597 315 7635 316 7655 31
7 7694 318 7715
<< /A << /D (116) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 624.06 450 631.636 ] /Subtype /L>
<< /A << /D (117) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 426.336 591.183 450.545 603.935 ] /Subty>
<< /A << /D (117) /S /GoTo >> /Border [ 0 0 0 ] /Rect [ 433.636 575.413 450 585.11 ] /Subtype /L>
<<
...

<< /D (The Startup Files) /S /GoTo >>
endstream
endobj
```

That is the

```
219 0 220 116 221 237..
```

pure numbers sequence, no string, label, token, command, operator, etc, please sincerely help clarify.. so appreciated

Comment: That is the object number and offset of each object in the ObjStm, it is defined in the PDF Reference. See page 102 of the 1.7 reference. "The stream data in an object stream consists of the following items:
•N pairs of integers, where the first integer in each pair represents the object number of a compressed object and the second integer represents the byte offset of that object, relative to the first one. The offsets must be in increasing order, but there is no restriction on the order of object numbers."

Comment: Just like @Ken says, it's an object stream which you can easily find out by searching the PDF specification for the **Type** value of the stream, **ObjStm**. If you didn't look at the spec because you don't know where to get a free copy, please read [pwyatt's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950220/1729265): You can get a free copy of the current spec from the PDF association.